# Format date from datepicker with dateformat

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I got this editText and when you click on it, it opens a datepickerdialog, so I pick a date and I want to show it in the edittext but i want to format the date locale. I want it to be mm/dd/yyyy for people in the us and for other one dd/mm/yyyy automatically.

I dont want to use simpledateformat, I want to use dateformat.

```
editDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //To show current date in the datepicker
                Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedyear);
                        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedmonth);
                        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedday);

                       // Date date = c.getTime();
                       // editDate.setText(date);
                    }
                },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
                mDatePicker.show();  }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself.
The reason I had so many problems because of the wrong imports.

I did it like this in the ondateset method:

```
java.text.DateFormat f = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
                        editDate.setText(f.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a mechanism to obtain user's Locale, then you can format date Java style

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
// Nov 18, 2014

df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.FRANCE);
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
// 18 nov. 2014
```

Comment: That's not a problem = Locale.getDefault() but it's just I need to change the date accordingly what locale I get

Comment: And that method above will take whatever locale you got